# не воспроизводится музыка

Tags: java, android

Я создаю медиа плеер. Я беру файлы из предложеного пути потом беру их название и кидаю их массив, а потом я массив передаются в адаптер и через адаптер воспроизвожу музыку, но вот проблема в том то что она у меня не воспроизводится.

Вот мое активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int position;
    RecyclerView spisok;
    File[] files;
    public static MainActivity Context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        spisok = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.spisok);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/VCCoffee/audio/");
        files = file.listFiles();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File f : files) {
            String name = f.getName();
            if (name.endsWith(".covers")) {
            } else
                names.add(name);
        }
        RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(files, names, this, R.layout.item);
        spisok.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        spisok.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    void getmusic() {
        File currentFile = files[position];
        String path = currentFile.getPath();
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(path));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Вот мой адаптер:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.AdapterHolder> {
    File[] files;
    int index;
    int position;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity.Context);
    int layout;

    public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View p1) {
            // TODO: Implement this method
            activity.getmusic();
        }

        TextView tv;

        AdapterHolder(View item) {
            super(item);
            tv = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            item.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    RecyclerAdapter(File[] files, ArrayList<String> names, Context context, int layout) {
        this.files = files;
        this.names = names;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (MainActivity) context;
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int p2) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(layout, viewGroup, false);
        AdapterHolder pvh = new AdapterHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tv.setText(names.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return names.size();
    }

    String getText(int position) {
        return names.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Позицию нажатого айтема передавайте в `getMusic()`, а глобальную уберите, а то вечно будет первая из списка играть. Также попробуйте поменять путь к музыкe (точный, с расширением `.mp3`). Не предусмотрена ситуация с отсутствием папки. Попробуйте вызвать `player.prepare()` перед `player.start()`. Выводите исключения в логи. Не надо этих издеватель

Answer (score 0):

Сначала надо указать **тип** и вызвать подготовку

```
... 
player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(path));
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```